# Filtering existing query by date

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

**This has yet to be answered with a functional answer.**

I have a few methods that Ive put together for some fun stats on a game I play often.

The method below will take the total count of all games played, match a player to the player list then show a summation of the total wins/loss/ties.

This is great, and functional.

However, due to popular demand Ive been asked to adjust the query to now take into account the date in which the game has played. I would like to filter it down to the last 30 days of summation. How can I do this?

I wanted to ask around before spending the time to rewrite the entire thing. Preferably, everything stays the same just filter down by date.

The date key for the database is `checkSumID` it is a UNIX timestamp.

```
private function topPlayers() {

        $topPlayersList = array();

        $playersList = DB::table('pickup_results')
            ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
                DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
                DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss"),
                DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Tie' THEN 1 END) AS tie")
            )
            ->groupBy('playerID')
            ->orderBy('wins','DESC')
            ->get();

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($playersList as $playerListData) {

            if ($playerListData->wins + $playerListData->loss + $playerListData->tie >= 25) {

                $avgPick = $this->getPlayerAvgPickCount($playerListData->playerID);

                $playerRecordID = $playerListData->playerID;

                $playerNameLookup = Players::where([
                    'player_id' => $playerListData->playerID
                ])->first();

                $playerListData->playerID = $playerNameLookup->player_name;

                $topPlayersList[$i] = array(
                    'name' => $playerNameLookup->player_name,
                    'total' => +$playerListData->wins + +$playerListData->loss + +$playerListData->tie,
                    'wins' => +$playerListData->wins,
                    'loss' => +$playerListData->loss,
                    'tie' => +$playerListData->tie,
                    'percent' => +$playerListData->loss == 0 ? 0 : round(
                            (+$playerListData->wins / (+$playerListData->wins + +$playerListData->loss) * 100),
                            2
                        ) . ' %',
                    'avg_pick' => $avgPick[0]->average,
                    'player_id' => $playerRecordID
                );

                $i++;

            }

        }

        return $this->sortArray($topPlayersList,'percent','DESC');
    }
```

There is a method that I wrote that does something similar, but more on a single person basis, but not sure how I can stitch the two together without a complete rewrite.

Here is that method

```
private function getTotalGamesPlayed30DayWinLossTies() {

        //PickupResults::where('playerID', '=', $this->getPlayerID())->where('checkSumID', '=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->timestamp)->count()
        $results = PickupResults::get();

        //$results = PickupResults::where('playerID', '=', $this->getPlayerID())->get();

        $count = 0;
        $wins = 0;
        $loss = 0;
        $tie = 0;
        foreach ($results as $result) {

            if ($result->playerID === $this->playerID) {
                $timeStamp = $result->checkSumID;

                $converted = date('m/d/Y', $timeStamp / 1000);
                if (strtotime($converted) > strtotime('-30 days')) {
                    $count = $count + 1;
                    if ($result->gameResult === 'Win') {
                        $wins = $wins + 1;
                    }
                    if ($result->gameResult === 'Loss') {
                        $loss = $loss + 1;
                    }
                    if ($result->gameResult === 'Tie') {
                        $tie = $tie + 1;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        return
            array(
                'total' => $count,
                'wins' => $wins,
                'loss' => $loss,
                'tie' => $tie,
                'percent' => $loss == 0 ? 0 : round(($wins / ( $wins + $loss) * 100 ),2) . ' %'
            );
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

When using the answer by Arun P

```
$playersList = DB::table('pickup_results')
    ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Tie' THEN 1 END) AS tie"))
    ->where('checksumID','<',$now)->where('checksumID','>',$thirty_days_ahead)
    ->groupBy('playerID')
    ->orderBy('wins', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

It will return 0 results. This is incorrect; I am trying to gather all games a player has played within the last 30 days only. Nothing more, nor less.

You can visit http://www.Krayvok.com/t1 and view the stats page for a working example.

I am trying to take the current leader-boards which displays all players total games played. I would like to filter it down to show only the players whom has had a game played in the last 30 days from today's date (rolling 30 day).

Comment: why don't you add a where clause and compare the timestamp to date_sub(now(), interval 30 day). which will give you the last 30 days of result

Comment: @MekjkrhG how would I do that? I tried doing a where on it and it gives me an error because of my counts. I couldnt get past the query :/

Comment: show me the update query you tried

Comment: @Kray In order to filter out the past 30 days, you need to have a date-column with your data - is that in the `checkSumID` column? (if so, its an odd name for it) -- alternatively, and preferably, can you show your table structure of the `pickup_results` table?

Comment: In your working example, you do `$timeStamp / 1000` when converting from a timestamp to a date in PHP. I believe you should also be able to do that same division on checkSumID before converting it to a unix time in one of the other examples to adjust for that. i.e. for MekjkrhG's answer I think you can change one line to be this to fix it `->where(DB::raw("from_unixtime(checkSumID / 1000) > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)"))`.

Comment: Have you tried `having` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your existing query,

```
$timestamp_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));

$playersList = DB::table('pickup_results')
    ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss"),
        DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Tie' THEN 1 END) AS tie")
    )
    ->where(DB::raw("DATE((checkSumID/1000)) >= '{$timestamp_from}'"))
    ->groupBy('playerID')
    ->orderBy('wins','DESC')
    ->get();
```

In your method `getTotalGamesPlayed30DayWinLossTies` there is a division by 1000 for `checkSumID` and I have included it in the query. The where clause for `checkSumID` has been altered to compare dates.

Try this an comment if you need any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$playersList = DB::table('pickup_results')
        ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win' AND checkSumID > '".now()->subDays(30)->toDateString()."' THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' AND checkSumID > '".now()->subDays(30)->toDateString()."' THEN 1 END) AS loss"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Tie' AND checkSumID > '".now()->subDays(30)->toDateString()."' THEN 1 END) AS tie")
        )
        ->groupBy('playerID')
        ->orderBy('wins','DESC')
        ->get();
```

Laravel creates the [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) date instance for `now()` as mentioned in its [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators). Chaining the above carbon methods ([carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)) returns the date 30 days ago.

All the `SELECT` statements would convert to something like this (when the current date is '2019-07-06') -

`COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win' AND checkSumID > '2019-06-06' THEN 1 END) AS wins`

This would count the results which were created **after** '2019-06-06' (in the last 30 days) **including** the current date.

Answer (score -1):

try this 
`from_unixtime()` returns a date/datetime from unix timestamp

```
$playersList = DB::table('pickup_results')
        ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Tie' THEN 1 END) AS tie")
        )
        ->where(DB::raw("from_unixtime(checkSumID) > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)"))
        ->groupBy('playerID')
        ->orderBy('wins','DESC')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Nope, doesnt change the query result.

Comment: nope :'(. It did not change anything about the query. Wonder if it has to do with the fact that the PlayerID is grouped? or the column checkSumID isnt being grabbed?

Comment: have you tried after removing the group by? the checksumID dont have to be grabbed to do a where clause

Comment: I need to group the playerID to show singular counts for the player. you can view this query result at http://www.Krayvok.com/t1 select "Leaderboards".

Comment: Any thoughts on what to do @MekjkrhG

Answer (score -2):

Try this one, Update your query like this

```
 $thirty_days_ahead = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-30 days"));
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("0 days"));


    $results = DB::table('pickup_results')
    ->select(DB::raw("playerID"),
    DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins"),
    DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss"),
    DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Tie' THEN 1 END) AS tie"))
    ->where('checksumID','<',$now)->where('checksumID','>',$thirty_days_ahead)
    ->groupBy('playerID')
    ->orderBy('wins', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Any thoughts on what to do @Arun P

Comment: @kray this will generate a query equallent to "select playerID, COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Win'  THEN 1 END) AS wins, COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Loss' THEN 1 END) AS loss, COUNT(CASE WHEN gameResult = 'Tie' THEN 1 END) AS tie from `pickup_results` where `created_at` < 2019-07-01 10:10:44 and `created_at` > 2019-06-01 10:10:44 group by `playerID` order by `wins` desc"  try execution that on your db, the reason that it returns empty might be because there was no entries in the last 30 days

Comment: I will update my OP with what I have and what its doing.